# How not to grow a career within software development industry and still manage to be employed?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, software-development

I am wondering if it possible to survive in the software development industry without thinking whatsoever about your career or giving any thought about where do you want to be within five or ten years in large firm. Can I survive if I just focused one tech stack and do that really well?

Comment: If you want to do non-trivial interesting stuff, you need to be able to work with others.  In that way you need to think careerwise.

Comment: jio, welcome new user.  What you describe is absolutely the normal situation. 95% or more of programmers do exactly this.  Programming is (a) very well paid and (b) very specific.  You've more or less literally defined programming!

Comment: This is probably not a problem when you're young. But for senior people, if you lose your job, finding one might be hard because of the salary cost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've worked with lots of developers who have done just this for their careers of 20 or 30 years and more. I wouldn't be overly surprised if the vast majority of developers are like this - it's just that they are invisible as they are also not writing blogs or tweeting hot takes.

Comment: One need only agree with this answer - that's it.